# Spring integration - relase messages in a loop (batches)

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I need to be able to receive messages from rabbitmq, do some transformations (from 1 input message, I create 1000 messages) and then process those 1000 messages in following way: I push messages in batches of 10, then sleep 5 seconds.

You can see the code below and the help I need is with last step - how to do message batching this way?

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow refreshFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                //get messages from rabbitmq
                .from(refreshInboundAdapter())
                //convert to POJO
                .transform(new JsonToObjectTransformer(RefreshRequest.class))
                //make 1 -> 1000 messages (but release in batches of 10, not all)
                .<RefreshRequest, List<ElasticMatch>>transform(m -> componentConfig.matchRefreshService().processRequest(m))
                //HERE WAIT 5 seconds and forward to rabbit in batches of 10
                .handle(refreshOutboundEndpoint())
                .get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean about "wait 5 seconds", but "release in batches of 10" is exactly a task for the Aggregator. You need to have some artificial `correlationKey`, configure `expireGroupsUponCompletion = true` and `MessageCountReleaseStrategy`.

See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator) for more information.

Comment: `matchRefreshService().processRequest` would contain code that would fetch some data from REST (in batches of 10) based on `RefreshRequest` message and then release this messages to `refreshOutboundEndpoint` in this 10-size batches. This is a bit different than aggregator (logically), because `processRequest` is actually source of data. Unless you thought that I make processRequest look like aggregator and release at batches of 10 then sleep then release 10 ... untill I release all 1000 messages?

Comment: M-m-m. OK. Let me rephrase your comment to determine that we are on the same page. You would like to do some custom logic based on one message and produce `1000/10` messages to the `outputChannel`. This can be done by `splitter` then - one-to-many component. Is it close to your expectations?

Comment: splitter seems ok. but I will not produce 1000 messages at once and then split them. I need to produce 10 after 10 and release it this way. so, I will have 100 rest calls in that component.

Comment: Right, you receive 1 message, build 1000 iterate them and return 100 by 10 and use this custom code for the `.split()`.

Comment: when you say build 1000 that means I have to wait for all 1000 and cannot push messages down the pipeline when I have first 10 messages for sending?

Comment: Sorry, you have to be more clear in the beginning. We went so far into business details in the comments but there is nothing on the matter in your original question. And as you see I still don't understand your task. Please, elaborate more with the requirements details.

Comment: If you say "release by arrival", I would still recommend to take a look into an aggregator

Comment: Task is to throttle messages intended to be used as recovery. Get 10 messages each 5 seconds from REST endpoint, enrich them with data from database and forward them to rabbitmq for further processing by other process(es).

Comment: No, still unclear what is that about. I would use splitter to build 1000 from the one, send them all to the `QueueChannel` on another side would have a poller with the `maxMessagesPerPoll = 10` with the `fixedDelay = 5000`, then process them over the REST and in the end would aggregate them by 10 size. Otherwise, please, provide some PoC on the matter and let's dig the problem from the code perspective.

Comment: Thanks for help as always. I'll manage to do something similar as you proposed in last comment.